# I keep getting NaN and i can't find out how to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, nan

It happens when it gets to `cost2`. I think the problem might be in trying to define `price2`, everything else works fine. I'm new to JavaScript so I'm sure it's a simple mistake, but any help would great!

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Gas Mileage</h1><br></br>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mpg, price1, distance, gallons, cost1, price2, cost2;

        mpg = prompt("Enter your car's miles per gallon");
        document.write("Your car gets "+mpg+" miles per gallon.");
        document.write("<br>");

        price1 = prompt("Enter the current cost of gas");
        document.write("Gas currently costs $"+price1+" per gallon.");
        document.write("<br>");

        distance = prompt("Enter the amount of miles you would like to travel");
        gallons = distance/mpg;
        cost1 = gallons*price1;
        document.write("To travel "+distance+" miles, it will cost you $"+cost1);
        document.write("<br>");

        price2 = (0.1+price1);
        cost2 = gallons*price2;
        document.write("But if gas were to cost 10 cents more per gallon, it would cost you $"+cost2);

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't ever call this Java again.  Java and Javascript are very, very unalike.

Comment: U usually get this error whenever you're trying to perform mathematical operations on a number with a string. could you please check if all the values are numbers, and neither of them is string.

Comment: Justin, did my answer help you? If you have questions about the answer, feel free to comment on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prompt` always returns a string.

If you want to use that input in calculations, you're going to have to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`:

```
var answer1 = parseInt(prompt("Question 1"));
var answer2 = parseFloat(prompt("Question 2"));
```

That said, the division and multiplication operators will coerce it's parameters to numbers.

The problem occurs when this coercion doesn't work: `price2 = (0.1+price1);`
There, because the `+` will just concatenate the 2 parameters as string, `price2` can be a string like `"0.11.54"` if `price1` is `"1.54"`.
Trying to multiply any number with an invalid number like that results in `NaN`.

Converting the user input from string to number solves that issue, since the `+` can then add the two numbers together, instead of concatenating them.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, was trying everything my instructor showed us in class, but it still wasn't working.